# Hardhat node doesn't work on typescript

Tags: hardhat, nodejs, typescript

Lets say I have a `00-mocks.ts` file inside a deploy folder(hardhat project) and the code looks ok:

```
const { ethers, newtwork } = require('hardhat')


module.exports =  async function () {
    try {
        const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
        console.log(accounts);
        const token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token")
        const instance = await token.deploy("testTokenName","testSymbol")
        await instance.deployed()
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
 
}
module.exports.tags = ["all", "Token"]
```

But the problem is when i run my node using `yarn hardhat node` my token doesn't deploy, and i can't see my logs, but node runs and it gives me signers with first balance of ETH.
I've used exact same code in `JS` and it works, but i don't know whats the problem with `typeScript`.

Even i tried to use it as a script using this command: `yarn hardhat run scripts/"filename".ts --network localhost` But still doesn't work.

Comment: try `npx hardhat run scripts/"filename".ts --network localhost` instead

Answer (score 0):

You should check your hardhat configuration files once, make sure all the chainId and url are correct. Then it should have work.

Comment: Actually I'm using yarn package manager, But still i installed this package that you mentioned but result is same, still i cant see my deployments and my logs

Comment: Don't use yarn use npx or npm because there recently there are few new changes in hardhat which yarn doesn't support.

Comment: Then should I run node with : `npx hardhat node` ?

Comment: No delete your yarn.lock file and install all the dependencies with npm, then use command `npx hardhat` to see if you can actually use node.

Comment: Still doesn't work, it compile my contracts but do not run script

Comment: Maybe all your dependencies are not installed. Install by the the below commands:
`npm i --save-dev @nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers@npm:hardhat-deploy-ethers ethers @nomiclabs/hardhat-etherscan @nomiclabs/hardhat-waffle chai ethereum-waffle hardhat hardhat-contract-sizer hardhat-deploy hardhat-gas-reporter prettier prettier-plugin-solidity solhint solidity-coverage dotenv @typechain/ethers-v5 @typechain/hardhat @types/chai @types/node ts-node typechain typescript
`
Also if the error continues then paste then edit your question and paste it.

Comment: I did it, even i deleted my `node-modules` and install it again. But still doesn't work.
Id doesn't return any error, when I write command line and hit enter, it do nothing.

Comment: Can you add some more code or push it on your github and paste link. I am not able to figure out where's might be the problem.

Comment: Here you go : https://github.com/alireza1691/Smart-Contracts

this is simple hardhat project, there is some contracts in contract folder and i want to deploy mocks before develop my contracts